# Como impedir o usuário de voltar para a tela de login após logar no flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Possuo o seguinte widget de login que após a requisição for feita com sucesso, ele adiciona na pilha de navegação a tela home e remove a tela de login.

Se eu tentar voltar da tela home para o login o app é minimizado. Porém, quando abro novamente o app abre-se a tela de login.

No meu `main.dart` é verificado se possui token. Se possui, é direcionado para a tela home. Caso não possua, para a tela login.

```
  checkHome() async {
    // Read value
    String token = await storage.read(key: 'token');

    return token;
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    checkHome();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    /// Chamada para solucionar o método.
    /// Nele também é acionado o `then()` que é
    /// que é onde pode ser capturado o retorno do futuro.
    checkHome().then((token) {
      temToken = token != null;
    });

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Cadê meu pet?',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow),
      /// Declaração do ternário para escolher qual page exibir
      home: temToken ? HomePage() : LoginPage(),
      routes: routes
    );
  }
}
```

Essa é a forma que trato a pilha de navegação no login:

```
if (response.statusCode == 202) {
      Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(response.body);
      // Write values
      await storage.write(key: 'token', value: map['token']);
      await storage.write(key: 'foto', value: map['foto']);
      await storage.write(key: 'nomeUsuario', value: map['nomeUsuario']);
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/login'));
 }
```

Meu cenário:

Possuo token, então estou na tela de home;
Clico no botão "voltar" do android;
O app é minimizado;
Abro novamente o app;
A tela de login é exibida.

Por possuir token, o esperado é que quando o app é minimizado, ao voltar seja aberto a tela home.

Comment: Recomendo que poste um código completo para que possa ser reproduzido e assim ser possível apurar totalmente o contexto do seu problema e apontar onde pode ser otimizado. Do modo atual que postou é complicado entender o que de fato foi codificado nos métodos e como você organizou tudo. Outro detalhe é postar também o que já tentou fazer para entender o problema, como por exemplo, o que notou ao fazer o debug do seu app?

Comment: @Leonardo obrigado pelo feedback, vou tentar organizar melhor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua estrutura não funciona pois você está trabalhando com um `Future` e não está fazendo o controle correto...
Você pode tentar duas formas

> 1ª Forma

Adicione o `setState()` e veja se funciona como quer

```
  checkHome().then((token) {
    setState((){
      temToken = token != null;
    });
  });
```

> 2ª Forma

Faça uso do `FutureBuilder()`

```
Future<bool> checkHome() async {
    String token = await storage.read(key: 'token');
    return token != null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Cadê meu pet?',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow),
      /// Declaração do ternário para escolher qual page exibir
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: checkHome(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if (!snpashot.hasData)
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

          return snpashot.data ? HomePage() : LoginPage();
        }
      ),
      routes: routes
    );
  }
```

Comment: Obrigado. vou testar em breve e te dou um feedback

Answer (score 3):

Você pode limpar a pilha de navegação após obter sucesso no login.

Use seu Navigator dessa forma para a nova tela:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>HomePage()),(Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Dessa forma você limpa a navegação e se o usuário tentar voltar irá minimizar o aplicativo.